# In what cases does a pointer not need to be dereferenced?

Tags: cython

I was surprised with some functionality of a pointer to a vector today.

```py
from libcpp.vector cimport vector

cdef vector[int] v = [1, 3, 6, 8]
cdef vector[int]* p = &v

print()
print("Print v")
print(v)
print(p[0])
print("Print v[1]")
print(v[1])
print(p[0][1])
print("Print v.size()")
print(v.size())
print(p[0].size())

print(p.size())
```

output

```
Print v
[1, 3, 6, 8]
[1, 3, 6, 8]
Print v[1]
3
3
Print v.size()
4
4
4
```

My understanding is that `v` is a `vector[int]` and `p` points to `v`. so that if I passed `p` to a function, I could access the information in `v` via `p[0]` aka. by dereferencing `p`. But what surprised me is that `p.size()` compiled, and gives the same size as `v`.

If I had called `p[1]` for example, it causes a `MemoryError`, so to access the second element of `v` using `p` you would need to first dereference the pointer, then access the second element `p[0][1]`

Where is the disconnect in my way of thinking about `p`. Are there other situations in which an explicit dereference is not required?

**Edit**

Looking at the generated c

```
  __pyx_t_2 = __Pyx_PyInt_FromSize_t(__pyx_v_54_cython_magic_021b4c4b5308665f3c7827dff9df4fb889b7abf1_p->size()); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_2)) __PYX_ERR(0, 16, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_2);
  __pyx_t_4 = __Pyx_PyObject_CallOneArg(__pyx_builtin_print, __pyx_t_2); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_4)) __PYX_ERR(0, 16, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_4);
  __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_2); __pyx_t_2 = 0;
  __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_4); __pyx_t_4 = 0;
```

It does in-fact look like `p.size()` is being transpiled into `p->size()`. That is quite interesting.

Thank you @DavidW.

Comment: It's largely "if you'd write `->` in c++, Cython will do it for you and your can skip the dereference". I wouldn't rely on that being a perfect description but it's pretty close

Comment: Ah ok. So `->` is c++'s way of combining a dereference and a `.`? So is `p->size()` is equivalent to `*p.size()`? And that is why `p.size()` and `p[0].size` are doing the same thing? Because cython knows `p` is a pointer, and uses `->` instead of `.`?

Comment: Yes. That's right. (You can also override `operator->` in c++ if you're implementing smart pointers though. I'm not quite sure if Cython can deal with that.)

Answer (score 0):

v is the variable that contains your values (like a house contains a family). p is the address of that house.

There is only one element in p because it's just one address.

p[1] doesn't exist because there's just one address.

p[0].size() works and is the same size as v because p[0] == v: you're accessing the same values.

EDIT: THIS PARAGRAPH WAS INCORRECT. LEFT IT FOR COMMENT CONTEXT
To access the second element of v through p, you'll need to dereference p (extract the values at the address), and access the second element of that: ***p[1]**.

I believe p.size() == 4 because the number of bytes for a pointer on a 32-bit system is 4.

Comment: This is cython though. so p[0] is how to dereference p. you can't use *p as this is python's unpacking operator.. it is p.size() that confuses me. I feel like it shouldn't work. Since like you said, p is just an address. but p.size()=4

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. You are correct. Are you running on a 32-bit or 64-bit architecture? That changes the size of the pointer datatype

Comment: p.size() = v.size() if v had 20 elements p.size() = 20.

I think DavidW is right that Cython defaults to `->` rather than `.` when dealing with pointers during the transpiling into c

Comment: You can disregard my answers, then. I guess I don't understand the answer, either. Sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: Thanks for helping!!! I think I got there in the end. I had to double check everything you mentioned just to make sure so clearly, I don't know it very well either.